# Other Effects of Artificial Gravity

Tags: gravity, science-fiction

So I'm writing a book where there is artificial gravity. I don't mean using centripetal motion; there's just some device that can create a force like gravity or actual gravity.

With this kind of technology, are there any other kinds of technology that would obviously come from it?

**Edit**: Are there any weapons or propulsion systems that obviously result from this device? I don't want to leave something out, or else people may wonder why it wasn't included.

Comment: Pretty much only useful being able to fall down some stairs on a space station. But really, we discourage this type of open ended "give me a list of possible uses" questions. Please add constraints to you question, for instance, "I want to make freight transport easier/cheaper, how can I do that with artificial gravity?"

Comment: To me it sounds like you might be able to create some kind of propulsion system.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity#Hypothetical_gravity_generator.2Fgravitomagnetism is a good place to start. Like Samuel said it is open ended.

Comment: The game Half-Life 2 had a Gravity Gun.

Comment: I think it's too broad, because you don't give us enough information on your gravity device, and we don't know it's limitations. For all we know, it could shoot a loser that would cause the sun to collapse into s black hole.

Comment: Look at Star Trek.  You have tractor beams, levitating vehicles, and floating restaurants.

Comment: Very broad, since there is no indication as to "how" this artificial gravity works. The mechanisms of artificial gravity, such as mass, energy consumption or even how tightly the field is bounded all make a huge difference in what other effects are possible.

Comment: FTL travel will be easier to obtain , Terra forming would be much easier , you could turn Jupiter into a star, permanent space habitations becomes simpler , the production of antimatter would be much much easier, one could remotely extract materials from planets, nuclear fusion would be MUCH easier, you could stop the expansion of the sun, hawking radiation power sources would be feasible , etc , etc , etc. The mere fact that their are so many answer implies that the question is to broad and/or qualifies as ideas generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the uses of artificial gravity, you can look at things like magnetism and, well, real gravity.

Magnetism helps keep your kids' drawings on the fridge, but it's also what powers railguns. Where magnets fail is that they only work on some materials, so your forces could fill in those gaps. Magnetism is also part of the same forces behind electricity, so it's possible your forces could be used in electronics.

As for gravity, it's great for bringing things together. If you want to go somewhere, and it's got gravitational forces pulling you there, it should be easier for you to get there. Similarly, if you're trying to get away from something, gravity might keep you from being able to do that easily.

Aside from mimicking or replacing these forces, your artificial gravity could also oppose them. For instance, electromagnetic shielding or antigragivty.

All of this really depends on the power and cost of your artificial gravity generators. If they're strong and cheap, they can probably be used for a lot of things. If not, people will probably just stick with magnets. The really interesting part would be if this technology is so massive that it creates free energy. Because then you could make perpetual motion machines, and do all kinds of impossible stuff. But like I said, it depends. Plug in your idea of how powerful this technology is, and see what you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You mention propulsion systems. One theoretical possibility coming to mind would be a drive which projects a strong gravity field in front of the ship (in the direction it wants to go). Imagine the force of gravity of, say, Earth on its surface, accelerating you - you get a constant ~10m/s² acceleration. Obviously, you'd make the field as strong as possible while still avoiding sheering forces high enough to tear your ship apart.

As for weapons, well, you could use the same principle to divert asteroids from their course towards a planet of your choice.